# Postrgesql - check constraint on table column defined as array

Tags: postgresql

I want to set a check constraint on the following postgres table:

```
 CREATE TABLE foo
(
     id int Primary Key,
     names           varchar(40)[]  
);
```

Since names is an array, I have trouble defining a check on each element of the array. 
The following constraint is my best guess (not working) :

```
ALTER TABLE foo
    ADD CONSTRAINT check_names
        CHECK (ALL(names[]) ~* '^[A-Z]')
;
```

Basically each element of names[] should be made of only capital letters.

Comment: Unfortunately, the [`ALL`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparisons.html#AEN20343) needs to be at the right side of the operator, so it won't work with any pattern matching operator in PostgreSQL. You could write an inverse operator if you encouter with this situation often, you could write a custom immutable function for this `CHECK` constraint, or you could [define a domain type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createdomain.html) and create an array of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like pozs commented on your post, you can not put a `CHECK` constraint like this on an array as far as I know (the real pro's may correct me here).

What you could do is write a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger that checks the value of the `names` field before it is inserted into the table. Effectively that would work just like a `CONSTRAINT`. Obviously, this will not work on rows already in the table.

```
CREATE FUNCTION all_caps_array_only() RETURNS trigger AS $$
DECLARE
  name varchar(40);
BEGIN
  FOREACH name IN ARRAY NEW.names LOOP
    IF name !~ '[A-Z]+' THEN
      RETURN NULL; -- Fail the INSERT
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
  RETURN NEW; -- Make the INSERT happen
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Worked fine.

Comment: You don't really need a trigger. Change the function to return `boolean` and then use it in a check constraint.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Good point, but effectively the same solution.

Answer (score 5):

Its doable even without a separate Trigger Function:

```
CREATE TABLE foo(
     id int Primary Key,
     names           varchar(40)[]
);

ALTER TABLE foo
  ADD CONSTRAINT check_names
    CHECK (length(regexp_replace(array_to_string(names, ''),'[A-Z]*',''))=0);

INSERT INTO foo (id, names) VALUES (4, array ['','3']);
ERROR:  new row for relation "foo" violates check constraint "check_names"
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (4, {"",3}).
```

Comment: Good solution so +1, but oh my golly so ugly. And the `CASE` is not necessary: `CHECK (length(regexp_replace(array_to_string(names, ''),'[A-Z]*',''))=0)`. A fine example of how to obfuscate what you really want to do!

Comment: This is also potentially very inefficient on large arrays that you process in their entirety twice even if the first element of 10,736 elements (give or take) is offending.

Comment: @Patrick As for inefficiency is concerned, valid point... but there's only so much that PG allows here at this moment. Ideally such inefficiencies are probably a ToDo for PostgreSQL itself (and not really a fault of this SQL) but yes, it still is a limitation as of today.